# Can 2 beams of ultraviolet light intersect and be visible where they intersect?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, laser, frequency

Is it possible that if you have 2 ultraviolet lasers, that are invisible to the human eye, and if you aim their beams to intersect at some point, that the place of intersection will show a lower visible wavelength of light, caused by interference of the light freqency?  Can any other form of heat or energy be generated at the intersection?

If so, can someone provide a link to the explanation?  I am curious about this.

EDIT:  I should add that the 2 lasers would have different light frequencies while they are both invisible to the human eye.  So, I am wondering about interference between light freqencies.

Comment: interference causes change in amplitude, not change in freq.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_(optics)#Optical_interference notice that the intensity is only thing which is changing.

Comment: Interference changes the spatial distribution of intensity **of the same frequency**.

Comment: Interference only affects like-frequencies as long as your measurement is time averaged. Instantaneous measurement would show interference between frequencies.

Comment: If all you care about is the invisible part, and not actually ultraviolet, then http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_excitation_microscopy is for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you say is not possible with interference. Interference of light does not produce new colors of light. Light would have to scatter inelastically off of some molecules to produce a down-shifted frequency (Raman scattering or some type of wave-mixing phenomena). The point is, the light should interact with matter to change its frequency.

Comment: [Why not?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterodyne_detection)

Comment: Heterodyning and Homodyning techniques need a mixing element. In electronics, a simple diode arrangement acts as a mixer whereas in optics, a beam-splitter cube acts as a mixer. Photons do not interact with each other. This is fundamental. You need an interaction to change the energy of a photon. (Also, interference is not observed with completely uncorrelated light).

Comment: I have never heard of a glass beam-splitter which can act as a mixer. This would make nonlinear optics substantially easier if it were true. I think you are confusing the beam-splitters role (giving two beams parallel k-vectors) and the mixing process which requires a material with a nonlinear polarizability.

Comment: *"Photons do not interact with each other."* I'll caution you that this is true in classical optics, but not in a fully quantum treatment. That said, light-on-light effects are very weak for ordinary light intensities.

Comment: @zephyr: I used the term "mixer" as in mixing photon modes.Frequency is not the only degree of freedom. You can also mix polarization modes.Perhaps the more accurate term is 'rotation'.See [here](http://people.bu.edu/teich/pdfs/PRA-40-1371-1989.pdf) and [here](http://pra.aps.org/abstract/PRA/v48/i4/p3265_1). dmckee:What do you mean?Even in a fully quantum treatment, I have never seen an interaction Hamiltonian for two photons.

Comment: @AntillarMaximus You don't need a direct interaction...they interact at the one-loop level.

Comment: @dmckee:I am not familiar with high energy physics, but thank you for the lead. I will look this up and hopefully gain a better understanding.

Comment: @Peter Shor - I am noticing on this link that what I am suggesting im my question might indeed be possible? : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_heterodyne_detection#Gain_in_the_detection

Comment: @djangofan: It certainly works with radio waves, although you don't get observable interference unless both beams interact with some matter that responds non-linearly to the radiation. I am not enough of an experimentalist to know whether you can make it work with ultraviolet light. You need matter (dust particles, smoke) to see a laser beam anyway, so it may be possible that you could find some dust particles that have the right non-linear reaction to the intersecting laser beams to produce visible light at the intersection.

Comment: If we introduce a medium (gas, crystal) that absorbs the ultraviolet light from the lasers, can a different (lower) wavelength be emitted? It's possible to get a higher (visible) wavelength emitted from absorption from two infrared lasers, but I'm not sure about the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have more luck using two infrared lasers - if you shone two infrared lasers at your eye (or at a camera) with frequencies that are half that of a visible photon, a small percentage of them would undergo two-photon absorption; two photons each with half the energy needed would be absorbed by a sensor element at the same time, causing the sensor to detect the equivalent of a visible-light photon.

The intensities would have to be very high for such an effect to be visible; I haven't done the calculations, but I'm confident the infrared lasers would completely cook your eye before you managed to see anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the appropriate non-linear media,
and both beams have a high enough intensity
(probably requiring pulsed lasers),
you may be able to have a visible effect
at the point inside the media where the beams intersect.
Such [nonlinear optics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/nonlinear_optics) are pretty difficult to get working in practice, but not theoretically impossible.

My understanding is that pretty much all [optically-pumped lasers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/laser_pumping) convert (typically incoherent) high-energy (short wavelength) photons into laser light with somewhat lower-energy (longer wavelength) photons.

Answer (score 0):

The basic reason the answer is NO, as everybody says, is because light, an electromagnetic wave, is an emergent phenomenon from [innumerable individual photons](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html). Thus your question boils down to :

**is there a photon photon interaction? can a photon scatter off a photon?**

The answer is : yes, there exists a [two photon interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics),  but with such a tiny probability that it is improbable to see a collective effect unless at very high energies .

[image: photon photon]

> A Feynman diagram (box diagram) for [photon–photon scattering](http://httphttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics://), one photon scatters from the transient vacuum charge fluctuations of the other

Note that there are four electromagnetic vertices here, and the [electromagnetic coupling constant](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/forces/funfor.html) that ends up as squared in the [calculations](http://www-pnp.physics.ox.ac.uk/~barra/teaching/feynman.pdf) is (1/137)^1/2, four times. This is a very small number and ensures the observations: that electromagnetic beams do not interact in vacuum except at very high energies when the crossection rises.

There are proposals for [gamma gamma colliders](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/pubs/beamline/26/1/26-1-kim.pdf), not exactly visible electromagnetic radiation as an output, but lots of elementary particles.

Comment: Nice answer, however in all of these things - people like to say no, and that is generally true at least for a time until we find out what we do not know. Like meta materials and cloaking the things we know now that once were said to not be impossible.